# Show an Integral Converges

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question is this, "Let $a$ and $b$ be positive numbers. Show that the integral converges, then solve it."
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1+e^{ax})(1+e^{bx})}\,dx $$
I'm completely stumped on this question. I took a shot at it but I'm unsure if I even got close to being correct.
What I tried was this:

First I got rid of a and b, then I got rid of the $1+$ portion in the denominator, and so the equation turned out like so:

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x}-e^{x}}{(e^{x})(e^{x})}\,dx $$

Which turns into this equation $ \int_0^\infty \frac{0}{(e^{2x})}\,dx $ which is easy to integrate and comes out to $0$. I'm unsure if this is correct, or even the correct way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "getting rid of" $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Try using partial fractions here - look to re-express the integrand as $\frac{A(x)}{1 + e^{ax}} + \frac{B(x)}{1 + e^{bx}}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1+e^{ax})(1+e^{bx})} = -\dfrac{1}{1+e^{ax}} + \dfrac{1}{1+e^{bx}}$. A bit more detail is: $ 0 < \dfrac{1}{1+e^{tx}} < \dfrac{1}{e^{tx}}, t = a, b$

Comment: Wow totally forgot that I could put it into partial fractions and solve as such, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a>0$

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{ax}}\,dx = \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+e^{x}}\stackrel{x\mapsto\log z}{=}\frac{1}{a}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z(z+1)}=\frac{\log 2}{a} $$
hence your integral equals $\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}\right)\log 2}$ by partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Wlog, we can suppose $a>b $.

we know that

$$a>0\implies 1+e^{ax}\sim e^{ax} \;(x\to+\infty)$$

$$a <0\implies 1+e^{ax}\sim 1 \,(x\to+\infty )$$

$$a=0\implies 1+e^{ax}\sim 2 \;(x\to+\infty )$$

thus

> if $b <a <0$,

the integrand is equivalent to

$$e^{ax} $$ 
the integral converges since $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^2e^{ax}=0$$

> if $0 <b <a $,

it is equivalent to

$$e^{-bx}$$

the integral converges.

> if $b <0 <a $

it is equivalent to 1.

the integral diverges.

The other cases $(ab=0) $ are similar.

Answer (score 0):

The hints let you compute the integral.  Seeing that it converges is easier:

Without loss of generality, assume $a>b$: If they are equal the integrand is everywhere zero, and if $b>a$ reverse the roles and we are just proving convergence of the negative of our integral.

Let 
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1+e^{ax})(1+e^{bx})}$$
Then for all non-negative $x$,

- Since $a>b$, $f(x) \geq 0$.
- Since $\frac1{(1+e^{ax})} < \frac1{e^{ax}}$. and similarly for $b$, 
  $f(x) < \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(e^{ax})(e^{bx})}$.
- Since $e^{ax} > e^{ax}-e^{bx}$, $f(x) < \frac{e^{ax}}{(e^{ax})(e^{bx})}
  = e^{-bx}$

So on the entire range of the integral, $f(x)$ is between $0$ and $e^{-bx}$.
Since the integral of $0$ converges (and in fact is zero) and the integral of $e^{-bx}$ converges to $\frac1b$, the integral of $f(x)$ must converge to some value between $0$ and $\frac1b$.